# How to call a widget from an Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I call my widget from any of the activities? For example, suppose I've a widget called "MyAppWidget". And I need to make it visible or call it from ActivityA and ActivityB inside the app. Is it possible? If so, what's the way?

I tried by using intent to call the widget as below. But it didn't work and crashed with Exception as a widget is not an activity.

Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyAppWidget.class);
startActivity(showContent);

Comment: Hi, Can you share more information? the code the widget class?

Comment: Hi @Dor it's same as this tutorial. http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-create-widget-for-your-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

App Widgets are miniature application views that can be embedded in other applications (**such as the Home screen**) and receive periodic updates. These views are referred to as Widgets in the user interface, and you can publish one with an App Widget provider.
Taken from [Build an App Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets)

If you want to create something that can be add to an activity your should read about Custom Views.

If you want to view your widget as activity, take a look [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-custom-widget-example/)

Good luck